# Covering map picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I wish to draw a crazy covering map showing charts any help?

Comment: Can you post some code showing your efforts so far? What features are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

[image]

I wasn't sure about the rules describing the blue lines, so i added some manual coordinates. You may change this into a function or else. Furthermore i did not add all chars for the same reason. But you may add them manually or according to a given rule as you wish. (same for arrows etc.)

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mycirc/.style={fill=yellow, dashed},
mydash/.style={ dashed}, blueline/.style={thick, blue},
]
\foreach \x / \y in {-5 / 2,-5/-2 , 5/2, 5/-2  }{
\draw [mycirc] (\x, \y) circle(.7cm);
\draw (\x -1, \y) --(\x+1, \y);
\draw (\x , \y+1) --(\x, \y-1);
\draw [fill=red] (\x, \y) circle(.1cm);
}



\draw[mydash] (0,3) --(0,-3);
\draw[mydash] (-2,2.5) --(-2,-3);
\draw[mydash] (2,2) --(2,-3);
% middle dots
\foreach \y in {-3,2, 2.5, 2,3}{
\draw [fill=red] (0, \y) circle(.1cm);}
% right dots
\draw[mycirc] (-2,1.5) ellipse [x radius=.3cm,y radius=.5cm] node (leftupper){};
\draw[mycirc] (-2,-3) ellipse [x radius=.5cm,y radius=.3cm] node (leftlower){};
\foreach \y in {-3,1.5, 2.5}{
\draw [fill=red] (-2, \y) circle(.1cm);}
%left dots
\draw[mycirc] (2,2) ellipse [x radius=.3cm,y radius=.5cm]node (rightupper){};
\draw[mycirc] (2,-3) ellipse [x radius=.5cm,y radius=.3cm]node (rightlower){};
\foreach \y in {-3,2}{
\draw [fill=red] (2, \y) circle(.1cm);}
%left elipisi

\draw[smooth cycle, blueline] plot[ tension=1]coordinates {(0,0) (2,0) (2.5,1) (2.5,1.5)(2,3.5)(-2,3.5) (-2.5,2.5) (-1.8,2 ) (-2.5,1.7 )(-2.3, 0.3) };
\draw[smooth, blueline ] plot coordinates {(-2.2,-2) (0,-1.5) (2.2,-2)};


\draw[->] (leftupper.west) --++(left:1cm);
\draw[->] (leftlower.west) --++(left:1cm);
\draw[->] (rightupper.east) --++(right:1cm);
\draw[->] (rightlower.east) --++(right:1cm);

\node at (-4,3) {$C,z$};
\node at (-4,-3) {$C,w$};
\node at (4,3) {$C,z$};
\node at (4,-3) {$C,w$};

\node at (-4,0){$w=z^2$};
\node at (4,0){$w=z^3$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please have a look at the discussion at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/should-we-answer-really-bad-questions